# Explanation on the problem and piece of code

Tags: c

[image: Link to the problem]

```
#include<stdio.h>

int factorial(int num)
{
    int result = 1;
    for(int i = 2; i <= num; i++)
    {
        result *= i;
    }
    return result;
}

int comb(int n, int p)
{
    return factorial(n)/(factorial(p)* factorial(n-p));
}
int main()
{
    int n, p;
    printf("%d",comb(5,2));
}
```

How is the combination being calculated based on the values 5,2?
What is the logic behind the program?

Comment: It isn't being calculated based on input, it's being calculated based on the hardcoded paramaters `5, 2`.

Comment: `comb` is `return`ing `5! / (2! * (5-2)!)`

Comment: Yeah but how is it doing so?

Comment: `factorial` is calculating `5!` like this: `1*2*3*4*5`.  It is calculating the other values in a similar way.

Comment: It's unclear what your question is.  What exactly are you unsure of?  What **specifically** don't you understand?

Comment: Beware of integer Overflow. You can’t do much multiplying of factorials without running into overflow problems.

Comment: For example lets say the argument is 3, 2 how is the output of the program 3?

Comment: You should understand the equation before you can understand the code.

Comment: Yes i did not understand the question sir please explain?

Comment: I got this question somewhere else and did not understand the working of it

Comment: Are you asking about the mathematics, or are you asking about the program that performs the mathematics?  That is -- do you not understand how the program works, or do you not understand the multiplication, division, and factorial operations?

Answer (score 0):

## Why is the output 10 for 5 and 2?

`n!` means the [the factorial of n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial). In this case `n = 5` and `n! = 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 120`

And `p! = 2` and `(n - p)! = 6`.

Therefore you have `120 / (2 * 6)`, which gives us 10.

### How does the factorial function exactly work?

When the factorial of n is computed, first a variable called `result` is set to `1`.

Then this `result` variable gets multiplied with every number from `2` to `n` inside the for loop, resulting in

```
result = 1 * 2 * 3 * ... * n
```

### Ask the user to input `n` and `p`

You may also want to ask the user for the numbers `n` and `p`:

```
int main()
{
    int n, p;
    printf("Enter n and p comma seperated: ");
    scanf("%d, %d", &n, &p);
    printf("The result is %d\n", comb(n,p));
}
```

Example:

```
Enter n and p comma seperated: 5, 2
The result is 10
```

Comment: And y is the output 10 is my question

Comment: This is 100% not an answer , and I want to believe the OP knows how to use variables .

Comment: @PranavKumar, I have updated my answer trying to understand your question and explain the way to the output.

Comment: Very well explained.